# Minifying RequireJS Javascript codebase to a single file

Tags: requirejs

I am new to RequireJS and maybe this is an already discussed issue but I could not find a clear answer or opinion about this.

I have an application working with RequireJS. It has a lot of JavaScript files loaded by Require as they are needed. Working as expected.

Looking to Fiddler inspector I could see that **all** the files were loaded when the application started. I believe that Require has made a deep traversal of all the references to JavaScript files and loaded them all in the beginning.

If this is the way it works I believe that it would be better to generate a single file, minify it, and load it using a `<script>` html tag.

If I generate one single file with all scripts, and pre-load them with `<script>` will RequireJS load them again?

Am I doing something wrong?

In a production environment what could be the better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not use excessive ??? as it may leave an unprofessional feeling of your question and may discourage people to answer for you. Keep strictly in facts.

Comment: Please do not be so picky.  The point of this forum is to answer questions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you want is the [RequireJS Optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).

The optimizer does the following (from the docs):

- Combines related scripts together into build layers and minifies them via UglifyJS (the default) or Closure Compiler (an option when using Java).
- Optimizes CSS by inlining CSS files referenced by @import and removing comments.

Here's [one article](http://www.svlada.com/blog/2012/07/02/require-js-optimization-part2/) on the topic for further reference.

Have a look also at [`r.js`](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js), the command line tool which includes the optimizer. Using `r.js`, you can generate an optimized build from an application file `main.js` with just:

```
node r.js -o build.js
```

where `build.js` is a requirejs config file containing your build profile (`baseUrl`, `paths`, etc.).

Comment: It means that I will need node. I will install nodejs and check it out. Thanks

Comment: If you project is on the simple side, also take a look at prunejs.com