# Package *.html templates in Require.js Optimizer?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, requirejs

How should one package the HTML templates (aka 'partials') in an Angular.js app when it is concatenated + minified for distribution?  Is there a good way of including them in that single file, or should I zip the folder which contains the `main.js`, `/templates/*.html` and `/styles/app.css` subdirectories?

The Require.js optimizer compresses all the JS files to a single file `myapp.min.js` that is suitable for distribution, but the HTML files are still referenced as individual files.

As background, the code is in a Node.js server:

```
public/
  /app/main.js
  /app/app.js
  /app/directives/*.js
  /app/filters/*.js
  /app/factories/*.js
  /app/other/*.js
  /app/templates/*.html
```

After running `r.js`, all the files in `public/app/**` have optimized twins located in a different directory `public/build/**`.  But the browser still looks for the templates in their original location, `/app/templates/*.html`.

So presumably the client would have to put them in that same directory, which seems like an unfair constraint.

[Minifying RequireJS Javascript codebase to a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337970/minifying-requirejs-javascript-codebase-to-a-single-file)

Comment: Can you post an example of how are you using the templates? You must use them through the `text!` plugin for the optimizer to bundle them. This means that in directives you will have to use the `template:` declaration (instead of `templateUrl:`) and rely on RequireJS to do the loading. Similar for routes (but you can also introduce an intermediate AMD module that registers templates with `$templateCache`, for cleaning up the code). I can elaborate on this, if you are interested.

Comment: That was *exactly* the clue that I was hoping for.  If you post as an answer I'll accept that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the templates through the `text!` plugin of RequireJS. E.g. for a directive:

```
define(["text!app/templates/a.html", "myAngularModule"],
function(template, myAngularModule) {
    myAngularModule.directive("theDirective", function() {
        return {
            template: template, // NOTE HERE
            ...
        };
    });
});
```

Or a route:

```
define(["text!app/templates/a.html", "myAngularModule"],
function(template_a, myAngularModule) {
    myAngularModule.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("some/path", {
            template: template_a, // NOTE HERE
            ...
        });
        ...
    });
});
```

Alternative, using `templateUrl` (just in case it is needed):

```
define(["text!app/templates/a.html", "myAngularModule"],
function(template_a, myAngularModule) {
    myAngularModule.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("some/path", {
            templateUrl: "app/templates/a.html", // can be any value actually
            ...
        });
        ...
    });

    myAngularModule.run(function($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put(
            "app/templates/a.html", // NAME MUST MATCH NAME ABOVE
            template_a
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: this is really cool. I have used the "text" plugin for RequireJS - but I didn't know until now that the r.js optimizer would bundle the html templates also

Comment: just to be sure I understand this - does this allow you to bundle the html templates with the r.js optimizer into one file? could you please show an example of what the requirejs.config file might look for that?

Comment: No special configuration is needed, you only need to make sure that Require understands the location of the `text!` plugin, so, either a path (e.g. `require.config({paths: {'text': 'location/of/textjs'}})`) or a map (e.g. `require.config({map: { '*': { 'text': 'location/of/textjs' } } })`).